# Protecting GND from RS-232 voltages

Tags: ground, rs232, protection

I have a project that uses this two wire RS-232 trick: http://circuitcellar.com/cc-blog/one-wire-rs-232-half-duplex-ee-tip-135/

It combines RX/TX into one wire while the other is ground.

However, I'm worried that if the user wires this thing up backwards, the +15V/-15V RS-232 voltages on SERIAL will be injected on GND(0V) and "let the magic smoke out".  Is there something I can do to protect GND from these voltages?

Here's half of the circuit, the other side would be identical to this, with SERIAL connecting to SERIAL and GND connecting to GND (hopefully) over a distance of about 5 to 30 meters.

[image: Circuit Diagram]

Comment: You're not going to let the smoke out of the ground wire. But you might let the smoke out of the driver chip if its output isn't protected against shorts.

Comment: @ThePhoton Yeah.  That's what I mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A compliant RS-232 output will withstand a short against anything from +25V to -25V.